# What is plex? "plex is missing" replacing disk in a mirror

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

A similar question exist which the author himself has answered by actually giving in on the question and it relates to Windows 8. I found an answer but it is for Windows 2016 Server which might be different.

I have created a mirror on Windows 2016 Server running as a VM (Oracle Virtual Box).

To test it I replaced one of my virtual disk with a new one after power down.
After boot I have strangely 3 disks in concern.

1. One disk from the mirror. 
   Disk 1 status: Failed Redundancy, online
2. The new unformatted disk which is supposed to be part of the mirror.
   Disk 2 dynamic status : online
3. A missing disk

I tried to select the missing disk an choose "Resynchronize mirror"
Nothing happened, then I tried "Reactivate volume" and I got "plex is missing"

What is plex and how do I rebuild my mirror?

Comment: @harrymc The referred link does not solve the problem, because the user in the end had to delete the mirror and create it again. One of the idea behind a mirror should be that one can replace a disk.

Comment: The post is still duplicate even if the answer is unsatisfactory. RAID is not as robust as it is said to be, especially if one does not follow the procedure.

Comment: I ask what is plex? That is not the question in the other link, second what is the right procedure replacing a disk? I think I do the simplest possible.

Comment: Plex is another name for a disk in RAID. "plex is missing" = "disk is missing".

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to choose "Remove Mirror" for the disk labeled missing, next you select the disk which already is in the mirror and choose "add mirror" a dialog box pops up and you choose the new created disk.

Comment: It is very bold to downgrade my answer considering the fact that I have screenshots which proves I am right (Windows 2016 Server)

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted -- this answer is perfect. I've upvoted you.

Comment: I imagine you were downvoted because you didn't really answer the question, `What is plex?`.